# Why std::string methods working with std::string_view are required to convert their template argument to string_view in their body

Tags: c++, c++17

In `std::basic_string` methods like `append` which work with `std::basic_string_view` the standard basically requires 3 things (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append):

> template < class T >
>    basic_string& append( const T& t );
>
> 1. Implicitly converts t to a string view sv as if by `std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> sv = t;`
> 2. then appends all characters from sv as if by `append(sv.data(), sv.size())`.
> 3. This overload only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>>` is true and `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, const CharT*>` is false.

What is the point of requirement 1 in presence of requirement 3? What would happen if requirement 1 was removed (like what code wouldn't compile/work as expected, etc)?

P.S. The origin of the requirements: https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2758.

**EDIT. Clarification of what exactly I don't understand.**

So as it is now with requirements 1-3 the `append` implementation in MSVC does exactly 1-3:

```
    template <class _StringViewIsh, class = _Is_string_view_ish<_StringViewIsh>>
    basic_string& append(const _StringViewIsh& _Right) {
        const basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits> _As_view = _Right;
        return append(_As_view.data(), _Convert_size<size_type>(_As_view.size()));
    }
```

Notice how the requirement 1 is implemented - very literally:

```
        const basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits> _As_view = _Right;
```

So why the requirements in the standard weren't instead formulated as something like:

> 1. Appends all characters from t as if by `append(t.data(), t.size())`.
> 2. This overload only participates in overload resolution if `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits>>` is true and `std::is_convertible_v<const T&, const CharT*>` is false.

and the implementation then would become:

```
    template <class _StringViewIsh, class = _Is_string_view_ish<_StringViewIsh>>
    basic_string& append(const _StringViewIsh& _Right) {
        return append(_Right.data(), _Convert_size<size_type>(_Right.size()));
    }
```

and no longer would create absolutely unneeded local variable with a copy of its argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misreading cppreference (and the standard). Neither document spells out the "requirements" as you do. They both make a distinction between requirements (when the function participates in overload resolution) and *behavior* (what the function does when it gets executed). Your list conflates the two.

For example, your item 1 is part of the function's behavior; it says that the function shall convert `t` to a `string_view`. If you took out item 1, then the function wouldn't do that and therefore it would become non-functional.

The question you are probably asking is why not just have an overload that takes a `string_view` as a parameter instead of a template with a bunch of extra stuff in it?

The reason for this is outlined in what you linked to. Because `assign` and similar functions already have an overload that takes a `const char*`, passing a string literal directly would create an ambiguity between the `const char*` overload and the `string_view` overload, because both are implicitly convertible from a string literal.

The "this overload only participates in overload resolution if" bit is what *prevents* this ambiguity from occurring. This is why it explicitly says that `T` cannot be convertible to a `const CharT*`. But enacting such a prohibition requires that the parameter type the function takes is not a `string_view`; instead, it must be deduced at the point of call from the parameter type. So it has to be some template parameter type `T`, so that it's possible to implement the overload resolution requirement.

And that means that the function's implementation has to do the conversion to a `string_view`.

---

> Appends all characters from t as if by append(t.data(), t.size()).

`t` may not a `string_view`; the requirement is only that `t` is *convertible* to a `string_view`. As such, `t.data()` may not be a function which `t` implements.

If you need an example of such a type, it would be *any string type* (other than `basic_string`) which is convertible to `string_view` (and not convertible to a `const CharT*`). And because `string_view` is such a useful lingua-franca string type, lots of user-created string types have been made convertible to `string_view`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now. The `append` was designed to be callable not only with `string_view` but user classes convertible to `string_view` too. As such, requirement 1 is necessary, otherwise example like `struct A { operator std::string_view() const { return std::string_view(); } } a; std::string s; s.append(a);` would obviously not work if `append` does not create temporary variable to convert user type to `string_view`.

Answer (score 0):

Part 3 is just saying that:

- the function won't even be called if the conversion to `string_view` is doomed to failure (e.g. a `static_assert` there would be really annoying; you want the compiler to try one of the other `append` overloads instead), and
- there's an exemption whereby the conversion to `const CharT*` doesn't count. Otherwise there would be an ambiguity with `basic_string& append( const CharT* s );`

In effect, it's describing a classic use case for `enable_if`.

This does not contradict part 1, nor is it redundant with part 1, because part 1 just says what will happen when the function *is* called. If part 1 were removed, nothing would happen, because part 1 describes what the function does.

Comment: Function does what part 2 says, which in absence of part 1 could have been spelled as: "then appends all characters from t as if by append(t.data(), t.size())". So what is the point of part 1 again?

Comment: @PowerGamer: `t` is convertible to a `string_view`, but that doesn't mean it *is* a `string_view`. There's no requirement that `t.data()` exists.

Comment: @Nicol So are you saying the compiler can chose templated `append` overload we are talking about over any other `append` overloads when called with something other than `string_view`? Can you provide an example like that?

Comment: @PowerGamer: the example would be *any string type* that isn't `basic_string` yet is convertible to `std::string_view`.

Comment: @PowerGamer Part 2 is about `sv`, and without part 1 there is no `sv`.

Comment: A `struct MyViewType { operator string_view() const; };` will be accepted by this implementation. A `struct MyViewType { operator string_view() const; operator const char*() const; };`  will not. (Presumably the latter will go to `append(const char*)` instead, because that's what the standard's authors wanted to happen.)